# ajax отправить json и вернуть результат

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

```
var jj = []; 

$('.pageblock').each(function(i,elem) {
        jj[i] = {
            name: $(elem).find('.name').val(),
            age: $(elem).find('.age').val()
        }
});

myJson = JSON.stringify(jj);
```

Собираю с экрана все загруженные имена и возраста, собираю их в json и отправляю на сервер:

```
$.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'kernel.php?cmd=savearticle',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        data: myJson,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        }
    })
```

в php скрипте просто пытаюсь вернуть полученное

```
print_r( $_POST['data'] );
```

Что не так делаю, не возвращает ничего. Кто подскажет?

Comment: Ну, как минимум желательно увидеть, что происходит в консоли браузера, какие ошибки там.

Comment: [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
saveArticle @ ?inc=pageeditor&type=article&ident=about:247
onclick @ ?inc=pageeditor&type=article&ident=about:80

Answer (score 0):

В отправляемых данных должен быть элемент с ключом `"data"`:

```
// async: false,
data: { data: jj },
```

Comment: [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

Comment: ругается на jquery